# How can I get correct date format for ambiguous temperature data?

Tags: r, date, data-manipulation

I used `raster` and `netCDF` package to import historical temperature data. But, the date columns has a strange date format and `R` complain about not in the standard date format. I used `lubricate` and `r base` to do date format coercion but still not getting out of this problem. Here is how my part of data look like:

```
> head(dat)
         date tmax  tmin
1 X1980.01.01 1.91 -0.04
2 X1980.01.02 0.77 -1.00
3 X1980.01.03 0.01 -4.37
4 X1980.01.04 3.08 -3.13
5 X1980.01.05 4.69  2.57
6 X1980.01.06 5.08  2.86


> class(dat$date)
[1] "character"
```

my `dat$date` column became `character` instead of `Date`.I tried `gsub` to get rid of `X` character but I didn't get it right. I tried also `as.Date` and `as_datetime` but still I didn't get right date format. Is there any quick solution to convert above date format to a standard one.
    head(napa$date)

any idea or any quick solution?

Comment: Just remove the `X` eg. `lubridate::ymd(gsub("X", "", "X1980.01.01"))`

Comment: lubridate and gub are vectorised. no need for the lapply

Comment: @RichardTelford I updated my original dataframe format, do you have a dynamic solution here? I'm bit confused actually. Thanks

Comment: In @RichardTelford's  first comment, instead of the character date put `napa$date`. That's it.

Comment: So it's `dat$date`. If you don't want to use an external package such as `lubridate`, after `gsub` do `dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date, "%Y.%m.%d")`.

Comment: @RichardTelford works like a charm, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was answered in the comments. Here are the different approaches together.

```
d <- c("X1980.01.01", "X1980.01.02")
```

The most concise:

```
as.Date(d, "X%Y.%m.%d")
```

In steps:

```
e <- gsub("X", "", d)
f <- as.Date(e, "%Y.%m.%d")
f     
#[1] "1980-01-01" "1980-01-02"
```

And note that

```
class(f)
# "Date"
```

A variation:

```
e <- gsub("X", "", d)
f <- gsub("\\.", "-", e)
as.Date(f)
#[1] "1980-01-01" "1980-01-02"
```

Or with `ymd` from the `lubridate` package

```
e <- gsub("X", "", d)
lubridate::ymd(e)
#[1] "1980-01-01" "1980-01-02"
```

Comment: Also possible to use `as.Date(d, "X%Y.%m.%d")` which is probably the fastest,

Comment: Thanks, that one takes the cake